# Prepend / prefix text to list items without class or id tags

Tags: javascript, html, css, list, html-lists

I'm working with the [Docsify.js markdown parser framework](https://docsify.js.org) and it automatically creates a sidebar from the headings in a document (unless you manually create a sidebar).

I have [some CSS that numbers list elements](https://codepen.io/markbattistella/pen/oNGWaPr), but want to convert it to JS as there are rendering issues when classes are added as the page scrolls (ie. adding `.active`).

Originally, I was trialling using this snippet but it doesn't output it as an auto incrementing hierarchical number system:

The sidebar that is generated is in the following format:

```js
var li = document.getElementsByTagName( 'li' );
for( var i = 0; i < li.length; i++ ) {
  var prefix = '1.';
  li[i].innerHTML = prefix + ' Title ' + i;
  prefix++;
}
```

```html
<aside class="sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar-nav">
    <ul>
      <li>Title 1</li>
      <ul>
        <li>Title 2</li>
        <ul>
          <li>Title 3</li>
          <ul>
            <li>Title 4</li>
            <ul>
              <li>Title 5</li>
              <ul>
                <li>Title 6</li>
              </ul>
            </ul>
          </ul>
        </ul>
      </ul>
      <li>Title 1</li>
      <li>Title 1</li>
      <ul>
        <li>Title 2</li>
        <li>Title 2</li>
        <ul>
          <li>Title 3</li>
          <ul>
            <li>Title 4</li>
            <ul>
              <li>Title 5</li>
              <ul>
                <li>Title 6</li>
              </ul>
            </ul>
          </ul>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
</aside>
```

I understand the HTML structure isn't valid with `<ul>` being a descendant of an `<ul>` but this is the code that is outputted and I have no control over it.

However, I want to be able to number the headings with sections and sub-sections:

```
1. Title 1
 1.1. Title 2
  1.1.1. Title 3
   1.1.1.1. Title 4
    1.1.1.1.1. Title 5
     1.1.1.1.1.1. Title 6
2. Title 1
3. Title 1
 3.1. Title 2
 3.2. Title 2
  3.2.1. Title 3
   3.2.1.1. Title 4
    3.2.1.1.1. Title 5
     3.2.1.1.1.1. Title 6
```

I am struggling to find a way to be able to target the first `<li>` (or the H1), and then being able to access the next `<ul>` via `.nextElementSibling` to continue the loop and prepend the numbering.

As far as I have gotten to at the moment is: `document.querySelectorAll( 'div.sidebar-nav > ul' )` and it's not much to go on!

I think I'm really out of my depth for javascript here, and was hoping that I'd be able to get some help on being able to loop through the `<li>` and `<ul>` elements to prepend the numbers.

Comment: You only want to prepend the numbers, or the last number of the title needs to be changed? The reason for asking is because the ```html``` does not match the desired result shared.

Comment: Also, your title says ```prepending```, but your ```js``` code tries to ```append``` it.

Comment: @prettyInPink sorry I'll update the input vs output - i messed up. and its supposed to be prefix or appending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is JavaScript to apply nested index numbers. At max there are only 6 header tags, 6 levels, so we can use recursive solution:

```js
let startLevel = 1;
let endLevel = 5;

function indexsify() {
  let children = document.querySelectorAll('#sidebar > ul');
  let numbers = new Array(7).fill(0);
  let depth = 0;

  children.forEach((element, index) => {
    recurse(element, ++depth, numbers);
  });
}

function recurse(element, depth, numbers) { //ul
  let children = Array.from(element.children);

  children.forEach((element, index) => {
    if (element.localName.toUpperCase() === 'LI') {
      numbers[depth]++;
      addNumberString(element, depth, numbers);

    } else if (element.localName.toUpperCase() === 'UL') {
      if (depth < endLevel) {
        recurse(element, depth + 1, numbers, startLevel);

        numbers.fill(0, depth + 1); //reset all next numbers
      }
    }
  });
}

function addNumberString(element, depth, numbers) {
  let strNumber = "";
  numbers.forEach((num, index) => {
    if (index > depth || index <= startLevel) return;
    strNumber += `${num}.`;
  });
  element.firstElementChild.innerText = strNumber +
    element.firstElementChild.innerText;
}

indexsify();
```

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li><a>Home</a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Chapter a</a></li>
      <ul>
        <li><a> Section a</a></li>
        <li><a>Section b</a></li>
      </ul>
      <li><a>Chapter b</a></li>
      <li><a>Chapter c</a></li>
      <ul>
        <li><a>Section a</a></li>
        <li><a>Section b</a></li>
        <ul>
          <li><a>Sub-section a</a></li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
      <li><a>Chapter D</a></li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

**Modify markdown itself:** As per the Docsify [plugin documentation](https://docsify.js.org/#/write-a-plugin) there is no direct provision to influence the sidebar content. Your plugin uses `hook.afterEach(function(html, next)` and the sidebar is generated separately. So you are trying to manipulate generated sidebar also. You are trying to do similar operation two times.
Why not use `hook.beforeEach(function(content)` and manipulate markdown itself. That way you'll have to do the numbering operations only once.
Here is a [demo site](https://cb7fz.csb.app/#/README) and the code [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-poincare-cb7fz?file=/index.html) for following sample plugin that manipulates markdown content:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/docsify@4/themes/vue.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/docsify/themes/dark.css"
    />
    <div id="app">Please wait...</div>
    <script>
      window.$docsify = {
        el: "#app",
        loadSidebar: true,
        maxLevel: 4,
        subMaxLevel: 5,
        homepage: "readme.md"
      };
    </script>

    <script>
      //plugin
      let myPlugin = function (hook, vm) {
        hook.init(function () {
          //remove '-' before Table of content entries
          let customStyles = document.createElement("style");
          customStyles.type = "text/css";
          customStyles.textContent = `.app-sub-sidebar li::before {
             content: '' !important;
             padding-right: 4px;
             float: left;
           }`;
          document.body.appendChild(customStyles);
        });

        //update markdown content before docsify parsing
        hook.beforeEach(function (content) {
          let lines = content.split("\n");

          let numbers = new Array(6).fill(0);
          let depth = 0;

          lines.forEach((line, index) => {
            let level = getLevel(line);

            //if not a header continue to next line
            if (level === -1) return;

            if (level > depth) {
              depth++; //increase depth
            } else {
              depth = level; //decrease depth
              numbers.fill(0, depth + 1); //set all next depth to 0
            }
            numbers[depth]++;

            let strNumber = "";
            numbers.forEach((num, index) => {
              if (index > depth || index < startLevel) return;
              strNumber += `${num}.`;
            });

            if (depth < endLevel) {
              lines[index] =
                levels[level] + strNumber + line.substr(depth + 1, line.length);
            }
          });

          //update original content
          content = lines.join("\n");
          return content;
        });

        let levels = ["# ", "## ", "### ", "#### ", "##### ", "###### "];
        let startLevel = 1;
        let endLevel = 4;
        let regEx = new RegExp(`^#{1,${endLevel}}\\s+.*`);

        function getLevel(line) {
          if (!regEx.test(line)) return -1; //not a header line
          if (line.startsWith(levels[0])) return 0; //h1
          if (line.startsWith(levels[1])) return 1;
          if (line.startsWith(levels[2])) return 2;
          if (line.startsWith(levels[3])) return 3;
          if (line.startsWith(levels[4])) return 4;
          if (line.startsWith(levels[5])) return 5; //h6
        }
      };

      window.$docsify.plugins = [myPlugin];
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/docsify@4"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

We need to override default CSS in `hook.init(function ())` to remove leading `-` in table of contents.

---

**Old answer:** You can have numbers directly on anchors`<a>` tags :

```css
.sidebar ul>li {
  counter-increment: item;
}

.sidebar ul>li:first-child {
  counter-reset: item;
}

.sidebar ul>li a::before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/docsify@4/themes/vue.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/docsify/themes/dark.css" />
<div id="app">Please wait...</div>
<script>
  window.$docsify = {
    el: "#app",
    loadSidebar: false,
    homepage: 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/OnkarRuikar/bb1d986f279dddceea9004a4bde3844b/raw/80fe153d6b8c1bb2b8e7035be7df1bb908779061/readme.md'
  }
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/docsify@4"></script>
```

If you generate numbers for titles in main section then they may get populated automatically in the sidebar. You can use [markdown](https://docsify.js.org/#/configuration?id=markdown) setting to write the script. Or you can try something like: https://github.com/markbattistella/docsify-autoHeaders

Comment: thanks @onkar for the answer. funnily I *am* the author of `docsify-autoHeaders` and I'm trying to extend it so that what I do in the body affects the sidebar too! but the structure of the sidebar seems to make it hard to do with my level of knowledge!

Comment: also I have created a "working copy" of using CSS counters - https://codepen.io/markbattistella/pen/oNGWaPr but when in production as the title tag becomes `.active` it causes the CSS to fritz out. so I wanted to so it purely in JS so it was "dynamically hardcoded"

Comment: lol  Now I get it! Looks like they haven't made provisions to manipulate the sidebar. You can override or add new CSS rules using Javascript from your plugin. See my demo plugin in the updated answer.  You can mix and match above solutions.

Comment: thanks @onkar the first snippet was very helpful and more than enough for me to go off and rework into my codebase. I didn't go down the road of adding the numbers to the markdown via `beforeEach` as I didn't want the headings to be tied to the numbers in the anchors - this way I could update the numbers or insert without affecting hyperlinks to those titles :) but hopefully someone else finds value in your little plugin

Answer (score 0):

You want to "do something" to every child of the outer UL, depending on its type - either increment the index at the current level and then prepend a label, if it's an LI; or else recurse to the next level, if it's a UL.  Given the HTML provided by the OP, this bit of code produces exactly the desired result:

```
function addLabels(element, prefix) {
    var index = 0;

    Array.from(element.children).forEach(element => {
        if (element.localName.toUpperCase() === 'LI') {
            index += 1;
            element.innerText = prefix + index + '. ' + element.innerText;
        } else if (element.localName.toUpperCase() === 'UL') {
            addLabels(element, prefix + index + '.');
        }
    });
}

document.querySelectorAll('div.sidebar-nav > ul').forEach(
    element => addLabels(element, '')
);
```

Also, you mentioned the idea of using nextElementSibling to get the UL's from the LI's.  That would work, but I think you'd end up with code that is less robust, less performant, and not particularly clearer.  But for the record, that could look something like this:

```
function addLabels2(element, prefix) {
    Array.from(element.querySelectorAll(':scope > li')).forEach((element, index) => {
            var label = prefix + (index+1) + '.';
            var sibling = element.nextElementSibling;

            element.innerText = label + ' ' + element.innerText;
            if (sibling && sibling.localName.toUpperCase() === 'UL') {
                addLabels2(sibling, label);
            }
    });
}

document.querySelectorAll('div.sidebar-nav > ul').forEach(
    element => addLabels2(element, '')
);
```